# How do I bind a WPF UserControl's DataGrid ToolTip FontSize to a variable defined in my main XAML window?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I've got a WPF Application.
I'm trying to set the `FontSize` and `Background` for the `ToolTip` on a item in a `DataGrid`.

**I have the following XAML snippet defined:**

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Foo}"
                                Header="Foo"
                                Visibility="Visible"
                                Width="*">
   <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
      <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
         <Setter Property="ToolTip" >
            <Setter.Value>
               <ToolTip Background="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow,Path=TBackground}" 
                        FontSize="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow,Path=TFontSize}" >
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo}" />
               </ToolTip>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Style>
   </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

**I have the following defined in the code behind for "MyWindow"**

```
private Brush _tBackground;
public Brush TBackground
{
   get { return _tBackground; }
   set
   {
      _tBackground = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged("TBackground");
   }
}

private int _tFontSize;
public int TFontSize
{
   get { return _tFontSize; }
   set
   {
      _tFontSize = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged("TFontSize");
   }
}
```

At run time I get the following errors:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'ElementName=MyWindow'. BindingExpression:Path=TBackground;
>   DataItem=null; target element is 'ToolTip' (Name=''); target property
>   is 'Background' (type 'Brush')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'ElementName=MyWindow'. BindingExpression:Path=TFontSize;
>   DataItem=null; target element is 'ToolTip' (Name=''); target property
>   is 'FontSize' (type 'Double')

What am I missing the binding process here?

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually have an element named `MyWindow` in your XAML?

Comment: That is the name of my main xaml window.  <Window x:Class="FooTest.MainWindow" Name="MyWindow" />

Comment: maybe like this, havent tested, not sure if it will work.
Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},                                                 Path=DataContext.TBackground}" Becouse DataContext of your dataGrid will be MyWindow and like that u can access it's property TBackground...i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TFontSize` property should be of type `double` and return a valid font size > 0:

```
private double _tFontSize = 20;
public double TFontSize
{
    get { return _tFontSize; }
    set
    {
        _tFontSize = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("TFontSize");
    }
}
```

You could then bind the `Tag` property of the `DataGridCell` to the window and then you bind the `FontSize` and the `Background` properties to the source properties of the window through the `PlacementTarget` property of the `Tooltip`:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <ToolTip
                    Background="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.TBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                    FontSize="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.TFontSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo}" />
                </ToolTip>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```

Because the `Tooltip` resides in its own visual tree you cannot bind directly to the window using an `ElementName`.

Comment: mm8: It's still not quite there. The Tooltip is for a datagrid contained in a user control; the fontsize/background is a property on my main window. I get the following error:  System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=MyMainWindow'. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridCell' (Name=''); target property is 'Tag' (type 'Object')

Comment: Try to set the Tag property to a RelativeSource. I edited my answer.

Comment: mm8: Wow. I guess I don't fully understand binding yet. I figured I could navigate to the correct location by using the main window name. Can you explain a little bit why your change worked? Thx.